# Website breaks after deployment after including react-chat-widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-widgets, react-chat-engine

My app breaks during production build when I try to use `react-chat-widget` widget.

When I delete the widget the problem goes away.

Here's my

App.js:

```
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import './css/main.css';
import SlideShow from './SlideShow'
import SearchAndBackground from './SearchAndBackground'
import ActionMenu from './ActionMenu'
import Contact from './Contact'
import Footer from './Footer'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage, addLinkSnippet, addUserMessage } from 'react-chat-widget';
import 'react-chat-widget/lib/styles.css';
import messageHandler from './messageHandler'


export default function App() {

  const [prevResp, setPrevResp] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    addResponseMessage('Hi! Let us help you find what you are looking for!');
    addResponseMessage('If you want to speak with our agents simply type "help"');
    addResponseMessage('Please type buy, rent, or sell for us to navigate to your likings.');
    addResponseMessage('If you are roman or ismail, please type pizduyar.');
    setPrevResp('Please type buy, rent, or sell for us to navigate to your likings.')
  }, []);

  const handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
    // Now send the message throught the backend API
    var str = messageHandler(prevResp, newMessage)
    setPrevResp(str)
    addResponseMessage(str)
    console.log(prevResp)

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <SearchAndBackground/>
      <SlideShow/>
      <ActionMenu/>
      <Widget
          handleNewUserMessage={handleNewUserMessage}
          title="Royar Help Desk"
          subtitle="online"
        />
      <Contact/>}
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error recieved from console:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.0.50/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/ahmet/Desktop/royar/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
```

Comment: Did you look in the developer console for errors?

Comment: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.0.50/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/ahmet/Desktop/royar/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /